# error with Attempt to read property "taqseet" on null while it not null laravel

Tags: laravel, has-many, attempto

I am trying to fix all issues but I get `Attempt to read property "taqseet" on null`.

##### Student Model

```
public function taqseet()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Taqseet::class, 'stud_prog_id', 'id');
}
```

##### CourseController

the error point to this line

```php
$link = StudentProgramLink::with(['sanad','taqseet', 'student'])->find($StudProgLink);
```

When I `dd($link)`, there's `taqseet` data:

```
#relations: array:3 [▼
    "sanad" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2490 ▶}
    "taqseet" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2486 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => App\Models\Taqseet {#2531 ▶}
        1 => App\Models\Taqseet {#2529 ▶}
        2 => App\Models\Taqseet {#2528 ▶}
        3 => App\Models\Taqseet {#2527 ▶}
      ]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
    "student" => App\Models\Student {#2547 ▶}
```

I can't find a solution for this.

I tried with `withDefault` function but it does not work with `HasMany` relation, it only works with `BelongsTo`.

Comment: What is the code giving you the error? Which exact line/function?

Comment: Yeah, you didn't show anywhere you're trying to call `->taqseet`, but basically, your code equates to `null->taqseet`, which isn't valid You'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77752293/edit) and include the code that triggers that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$taqseet = $link->taqseet;
```

This will get the taqseet data: